# Affect of choosing different combinations of variables for multivariate regression

Tags: statistics, probability, regression, multivariate

If I have variables x1,x2,x3,and x4 that have correlation coefficients −0.9,−0.5,0.5, and 0.9 to another variable y, what is the effect of choosing different combinations of them in a multivariate regression. Should I not use the negative ones (−0.9−0.9 and −0.5−0.5), or should I only use the most strongly correlated (ie −0.9−0.9 and 0.90.9)?

Comment: This is a statistics question but it's too basic for that website, I suggest you read up on multiple regression as it seems your global understanding of multiple regression is lacking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because more of a stats question but quite basic.